# How can I make the Resharper Add-on accept RequestID as a parameter instead of RequestId

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

Given the following function:

```
public SomeClass(int RequestID)
{
  // blah
}
```

Resharper complains that my parameter should be `requestId` (which doesn't make sense first of all, because the .NET API uses `UpperCamelCase` most of the time for their public methods. I went into the configuration and changed the `lowerCamelCase` to `UpperCamelCase`.

Now Resharper complains that instead of `RequestID`, it should be `RequestId`. Thats a little better, but I'm the kind of guy that likes `ID` and not `Id`. Anyone got a configuration fix for this?

Comment: Id does make sense, because It's not I Dentification, it is Identification.  Hence, Id would be the appropriate camelcasing.

Comment: @Stefan thats not the point. I want what I want. Not what you think is appropriate.

Comment: The .Net API does not use `UpperCamelCase` for parameter names, it uses `lowerCamelCase`.

Comment: I was simply commenting on what you said: "which doesn't make sense first of all, because the .NET API uses UpperCamelCase most of the time for their public methods"  It's perfectly fine to want it that way.  I was just pointing out that it does, in fact, make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add ID to the Abbreviations list. The Intellisense menu should have that option.

To manage your abbreviations, go to

Resharper -> Options -> Languages -> Common -> Naming Styles -> Advanced Settings..

Comment: Just an update that in VS 2010 with ReSharper 6.1 the list of abbreviations now appears under ReSharper/Options/Code Editing/C#/C# Naming Style/Advanced Settings - at the bottom of the panel is a text area with a space-separated list of uppercase abbreviations. This took me a while to locate, thought it might be helpful to others :)